# Question on measurability

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I need help to prove that :

> If $(T,\mathcal{A})$ is measurable space, and $U$ a metric space , we say that $f:T\rightarrow U$ is (strongly) measurable if one of the following equivalent properties is satisfied:
>
> 1. $f$ is $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}(U))$-measurable and $f(T)$ is separable
> 2. $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions assuming a countable number of values.
> 3. $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of measurable functions assuming a countable number of values .

Please, thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify: you need to prove the equivalence of these conditions?

Comment: yes! , and why if one of them is true then f is strongly measurable

Comment: What then do you use as a definition of strongly measurability?

Comment: Ah, this is the only definition in the book ! so i muste prove the equivalence between 1 2 and 3 ! but how ?

Comment: My point is rather that you shall only prove the equivalence, and use any of 1-2-3 as a definition. So *why if one of them is true then f is strongly measurable* is not something you have to verify. I don't know how to approach equivalence, though, at the moment. Perhaps, you shall take an inspiration from the case of $U = \Bbb R$

Comment: please , what is the meaning of (assuming a countable number of values )?

Comment: It means that such function $\phi$ is of the form $\phi(x) = \phi_i$ for $x\in A_i$, where $i\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: ah ,ok and for 2) we must prove that : $f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x), \forall x\in T$ ?

Comment: Exactly ${{{}}}$

Comment: if i suppose that f(T) is separable , then ther existe un sequence dense in $f(T)$ , but i don't know how to continue

Comment: if $(u_n)$ is a dense sequence on $f(T)$, why we have $f(T)=\bigcup B(u_k,1/n)$ please